# Same element id's on different pages of AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm very new to AngularJS, and am working to convert an existing web application written using JQuery and Bootstrap to one using AngularJS and Ionic.

I have 3 pages in my web application, each with a html5 canvas and a button. The canvas layout and styling are exactly the same on each page, however the button draws a different thing to each canvas, e.g. on page 1 draw a dog, page 2 a cat, and page 3 a chicken.

Because of this, I use the same element ID's between the three pages, e.g. '#myCanvas' for the canvas. I have a Javascript object called 'Drawer', which draws the relevant thing to '#myCanvas' when the relevant button is pressed.

When converting to AngularJS, I placed each page into a template, and converted the 'Drawer' object into a factory called DrawFactory. Each page is linked to a different controller that uses DrawFactory.

My problem is that, say for example I'm on page 2 and click the draw cat button, it draws it to the #myCanvas on page 1. Previously this wasn't a problem as each page loaded separately and therefore all ids were unique.

How can I achieve what I want without renaming each of the canvases to (for example) #myCanvas1, #myCanvas2, #myCanvas3- and creating 3 separate DrawFactories that individually draw to one of them?

I'm sure I'm just missing some key AngularJS concept. Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned that each canvas is in a different page. How is each page loaded? Are you using AngularJS's routing with `ng-view` directive?

Comment: @callmekatootie Yes, except I'm using what I think is ionic's version which is `ion-nav-view`. Here is a [screenshot](http://gyazo.com/8f981bd8ab24de967c18eda739be5aec) of my routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having your code posted, I suspect you may still be using jQuery selectors to find elements (e.g. `$('#myCanvas')`). You may wish to restructure your code to behave like this at a high level.

```
<div ng-controller="PageOneCtrl">
  <drawing source="animal"></drawing>
  <button ng-click="drawAnimal()">Draw</button>
</div>
```

The controller would be defined similar to the following:

```
angular.module('app').controller('PageOneCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.animal = null;

  $scope.drawAnimal = function () {
    $scope.animal = 'dog.png';
  };
});
```

And the drawing directive like so:

```
angular.module('app').directive('drawing', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      source: '='
    },
    template: '<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('source', function (newSource) {
        if (!newSource) return;

        var context = element.getContext('2d'),
            image = new Image(100, 100);

        image.src = newSource;
        image.onload = function () {
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        };
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time out to write this great answer! So am I understanding this correctly in that directives are the way forward for controlling a page's UI in Angular?

Comment: Yes, directives are a very powerful piece of Angular. They should be used for manipulating DOM elements and events. However, a lot of a page's UI can be managed purely by Angular controllers. For instance, had you just wanted to display an image instead of manipulating a canvas, it would have been preferable to do this all the logic in a controller and allow an `<img ng-if="animal" ng-src="{{animal}}" />` to handle the view.

Comment: How does this prevent the draw button on page two drawing an image to the canvas on page one though?

Comment: Each of your pages would have its own controller. I show the example code for `PageOneCtrl`, but you'd have others for page 2 and 3. Each page would also be defined with its own template similar to the first code block.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. Thanks. If the canvas I'm drawing too is an element within a larger structure of elements in the template of the directive, and not just a stand-alone canvas like in the directive in your example, how would I access it?

Comment: Sharing state across controllers can be a tough problem. There are many ways to do this, including events and services. My suggestion is to use an angular `value` and `$scope.$watch` to allow controllers to change the value and others who are concerned about it to be updated with those changes. If you create a Plunker with an example of what you are talking about, I may be able to assist further.